# Deselect item listview without getting pushed to new page (work around for iOS bluetooth pairing)

Tags: c#, ios, listview, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've got a listview with bluetooth devices that I'm connecting to. In order to pair with the devices in iOS (I'm using Xamarin.Forms) I need to be able to click the device twice in the listview (because of the pop-up saying pair for iOS) which i cannot do because that certain device has already been selected. I dont need to be pushed to another page I just want to deselect the device I just selected.

This is my listview:

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListViewXname"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeviceItemModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
          RowHeight="90" >
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ViewCell>
                      <ContentView
                          Margin="10">
                          <Grid
                              HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                              VerticalOptions="Fill">
                              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <StackLayout
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label
                                      TextColor="Black"  
                                      Text="{Binding Name}"
                                      FontSize="Large" />
                                    <Label
                                      Text="{Binding Id}"
                                      TextColor="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource BluetoothIdToColorConverter}}" />                                      
                              </StackLayout>
                          </Grid>
                      </ContentView>
                  </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <ListView.Footer>
              <ContentView />
          </ListView.Footer>
      </ListView>
```

This is the code I have for finding devices in my ViewModel.

```
private DeviceItemModel _selectedDeviceItemModel;

public DeviceItemModel SelectedDeviceItemModel
    {
        get => _selectedDeviceItemModel;
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedDeviceItemModel)
            {
                _selectedDeviceItemModel = value;

                if (_selectedDeviceItemModel != null)
                {
                    ConnectToDevice(_selectedDeviceItemModel.Device);
                    //ClearDevices();
                }
                SelectedDeviceItemModel = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option (ideally) would be to connect and get pushed to the new page when selecting pair from the pop-up.

I appreciate all the help I can get, thanks.

Comment: use the ItemTapped event, which will fire every time an item is tapped.  ItemSelected will not, unless you manually clear the selection first